# MySQLi prepared statement not taking valid query that calls a procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$prepared = $db->prepare("
        SET @content = ?;

        CALL add_interest_if_not_exists( @content );

        SET @iid = (SELECT interests_id
                    FROM interests
                    WHERE content = @content);

        REPLACE INTO profile_interests (user_id, interests_id, likes)
        VALUES (
            ?,
            @iid,
            ?
        )
    ");
echo $db->error;
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL add_interest_if_not_exists( @content ); SET @iid = (SELECT i' at line 3

The query works using MySQL workbench (hard-coded values). Why won't it in my prepared statement...

Comment: Why not use a single stored procedure and call it as prepared statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a single query but a set of queries.

Therefore you have to run them one by one, each with separate `query()` or `prepare()/execute()` call.

Comment: How come I can run the last 2 together? Is it because one is a sub query?

Comment: OK so I broke them up but that was causing other problems with having a subquery with a trigger so I just made a store procedure to do what I initially wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_user_interest(p_content varchar(200), p_user_id int,p_likes int)
BEGIN 

    CALL add_interest_if_not_exists( p_content );

    SET @iid = (SELECT interests_id
                FROM interests
                WHERE content = p_content);

    REPLACE INTO profile_interests (user_id, interests_id, likes)
    VALUES (
        p_user_id,
        @iid,
        p_likes
    );

END
```

End you will call as single prepared statement

```
$prepared = $db->prepare("CALL add_user_interest( ?, ? , ? )");
```

Comment: he is using mysqli, for starter.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  thansk for the advice... I changed my answer

Comment: @IvanCachicatari look at my previous comment :)